# Jquery replacewith() function is not working in my page

Tags: jquery, html

I want to replace the text of button. I want to replace "Read more" text with "Läs mer". U can check the URL:http://www.hummingbird.se/blogg-test/

I am trying this code. 
HTML

```
<div class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-left">
<a href="http://www.hummingbird.se/kryssning-fran-hawaii/" class="vc_gitem-link vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-flat vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink" title="Read more">Read more</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $(".vc_btn3-left > a").replaceWith("Läs mer");
});
```

Comment: Please create a minimal, reproducible example code and add it to your question instead of adding links to big websites where it is difficult for people to find out what you are trying to do. I see that you have received valid solutions to your question (which work on your sample code posted in your question here), but they probably didn't work for you on your site (because the code posted here may not reflect the problem you face on your website. If that is the case, please change the posted code).

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $(".vc_btn3-left > a").text("Läs mer");
});
```

```html
<div class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-left">
<a href="http://www.hummingbird.se/kryssning-fran-hawaii/" class="vc_gitem-link vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-flat vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink" title="Read more">Read more</a>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

You can try like this, `text()` will replace with new text

```
$(".vc_btn3-left > a").text("Läs mer");
```

Comment: Put `alert()` in your `ready` function and check alert is showing or not

Comment: alert is coming

Comment: @RashmiS - The example above _does work_ with the HTML you provided. Are you sure that the HTML is exactly as you provided in your question? - https://jsfiddle.net/4v2zybg8/

Comment: @RashmiS something you are missing in your code check html and js code properly

Comment: i stored value of .html() function in variable and alert it. Its showing undefind in alert.u can visit the site url which i have mention in the post.

Comment: @RashmiS - That is probably because your _selector_ is wrong. Are you sure that your `a` is directly under `vc_btn3-left`?

Comment: @RashmiS - The element `vc_btn3-left` isn't on that page.

Comment: @RashmiS or either create code snippet so i can figure it out what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".vc_btn3-left > a").html("Läs mer");
```

That should replace the html content of that class.